# call web service from Android emulator marshmallow

Tags: java, android, эмулятор, adb

Написал под андроид простой клиент, который должен дергать веб-сервис (сервис крутиться на tomcat на той же машинке, где я и под андройд разрабатываю), использовал JAX-WS. Да, библиотека тяжелая, и может быть это не так правильно как хотелось бы и т.д. но вопрос не в этом.

Дело в том что при вызове сервиса в коде есть строчка с методом `getPort()`, ну а потом у полученного объекта уже вызываем нужный метод сервиса, в общем он где то внутри сам хватает endpoint равный `localhost:8080/...` и шлет на него запрос. Соответственно, тестирую я это все используя android emulator marshmallow nexus 6.

В итоге он не сервис из эмулятора вызывает, а пытается через google найти что такое localhost. Я не могу найти способ подменить этот localhost на реальный ip-к моего компа. Я уже пробовал поправить на эмуляторе hosts, но безуспешно так как когда доходит дело до непосредственной правки файла hosts я получаю ошибку типа file system read-only. Я перечитал кучу сайтов, где там пытаются перемонтировать с параметрами mount -o rw, remount /system и еще много всего (я даже в папке tomcat нашел этот wsdl и ручками поправил его), но ничего это не помогает. система через ADB открыта только на чтение. Есть у кого какие нибудь идеи как решить данную простую с виду проблему ? Уже второй день бьюсь, но не могу ничего придумать, хоть прокси руками пиши.

Код

```
AuthorizationMainClassService mainClassService = new AuthorizationMainClassService();
AuthorizationMainClass mainClass = mainClassService.getPort(new QName("http://service.testservice.com", "AuthorizationMainClass"), 
        AuthorizationMainClass.class);
//System.out.println(mainClass.);
System.out.println(mainClass.doRegistration("123456789", "123456789", "Vasiliy2016", "Pupkin2016", "Ivanovich2016", "Vasiliy2016@mail.ru"));
```

Comment: код покажите, как вы устанавливаете соединение.

Comment: там все на backend делается, я не устанавливаю сам соединение.

Comment: он сам все с WSDL файла берет

Comment: подождите, вы frontEnd и backEnd запустили на Android-эмуляторе?

Comment: по сути я просто с помощью wsimport сгенерил набор классов используя ссылку на wsdl и просто делаю вызов

Comment: на одном компе стоит tomcat на котором запущен мой сервис.

Comment: на том же компе я запустил android studio и в ней написал код, там же запустил эмулятор и попытался вызвать сервис

Comment: все делается на одном ноуте

Comment: в Eclipse я протестировал все работает и вызывается нормально, как только я засовываю код в android studio в метод и через эмулятор пытаюсь сделать вызов, ничего не срабатывает.

Comment: в эмуляторе он берет ссылку на localhost, если ее заменить на реальный ipк то все будет как надо. вот только как это сделать я не могу придумать

Answer (score 1):

я похоже понял, вы на эмуляторе пытаетесь стучаться на LocalHost. Только на эмуляторе Localhost это и есть сам эмулятор. И вам нужно стучаться на IP компьютера, на котором запущен эмулятор. Эмулятор создает виртуальную сеть, и у компьютера, на котором он запущен в этой сети есть  всегда статичнай IP.
Его IP всегда `10.0.2.2`. [Пруф\сорц](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline.html#networkaddresses)

Comment: Дааааа ). Как его гада обмануть? ))))

Comment: @kinderus, очевидно же, что вместо `localhost` указать `10.0.2.2`

Comment: вот ты капитан очевидность то )))), ты думаешь я не знаю ?! )), в том то вся и проблема что я не знаю как это сделать, я же JAX-WS использую, там все на классах и методах, там нет метода типа setDestination или что то вроде того, там просто getPort по Qname, а дальше просто методы моего сервиса.

Comment: где-то это должно указываться.